# Efficient multi-row vector

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns, vector, dry

I need an efficient implementation of a vector with multiple rows, each having the same number of columns, which is not too ugly in C++. Currently I have the following:

```
class BaseVector {
protected: // variables
  int64_t _capacity;
  int64_t _nColumns;

protected:
  template<typename taItem> void Allocate(taItem * &p, const int64_t nItems) {
    p = static_cast<taItem*>(MemPool::Instance().Acquire(sizeof(taItem)*nItems));
    if (p == nullptr) {
      __debugbreak();
    }
  }
  template<typename taItem> void Reallocate(taItem * &p, const int64_t newCap) {
    taItem *np;
    Allocate(np, newCap);
    Utils::AlignedNocachingCopy(np, p, _nColumns * sizeof(taItem));
    MemPool::Instance().Release(p, _capacity * sizeof(taItem));
    p = np;
  }
  // Etc for Release() operation

public:
  explicit BaseVector(const int64_t initCap) : _capacity(initCap), _nColumns(0) { }
  void Clear() { _nColumns = 0; }
  int64_t Size() const { return _nColumns; }
};

class DerivedVector : public BaseVector {
    __m256d *_pRowA;
    __m256i *_pRowB;
    uint64_t *_pRowC;
    uint8_t *_pRowD;
    // Etc. for other rows
public:
    DerivedVector(const int64_t nColumns) : BaseVector(nColumns) {
        Allocate(_pRowA, nColumns);
        Allocate(_pRowB, nColumns);
        Allocate(_pRowC, nColumns);
        Allocate(_pRowD, nColumns);
        // Etc. for the other rows
    }
    void IncSize() {
        if(_nColumns >= _capacity) {
            const int64_t newCap = _capacity + (_capacity >> 1) + 1;
            Reallocate(_pRowA, newCap);
            Reallocate(_pRowB, newCap);
            Reallocate(_pRowC, newCap);
            Reallocate(_pRowD, newCap);
            // Etc. for other rows
            _capacity = newCap;
        }
        _nColumns++; 
    }
    ~DerivedVector() {
        // Call here the Release() operation for all rows
    }
};
```

The problem with this approach is that there can be 30 rows, so I have to type manually (and repeat myself) 30 times `Allocate`, 30 times `Reallocate`, 30 times `Release`, etc.

So is there a way in C++ to keep this code DRY and fast? I am ok with macros, but not heavy polymorphism in each access to a cell in the vector because this would kill performance.

Comment: How about a container wrapping `vector<vector< >>`? Or maybe just use some existing matrix classes?

Comment: Yep, don't reinvent the wheel. Also all matrix libraries use contiguous arrays.

Comment: Remember that array indexing is just pointer arithmetic. And that an array of arrays is really just a single large contiguous area of memory. You can create this large area yourself (using e.g. a `std::vector`) and do your own arithmetic to get the correct cell in that area. There are plenty of examples all over the Internet if you just search a little, but also easy to figure out yourself using just pen and paper.

Comment: @VTT, `vector<vector<T>>` wouldn't work because we don't have a single type `T`. And `vector` of some structure with my rows would be too slow, even with a custom allocator. Also because I need rows to lay in continuous memory, while a structure would interleave the columns of a row.

Comment: @SergeRogatch What about using `std::vector<std:variant>` ? This would account for the different types. You just need to write nice access function. Thus, you have a contiguous memory layout and different type are possible.

Comment: The number and types of rows are fixed? maybe a `std::tuple` is the structure you are looking for. `std::tuple<__m256d*,__m256i*,uint64_t *, uint8_t *> _pRows`. Then you would need some template magic and can iterate over the tuple at compile-time.

Comment: @Serge Rogatch, seems to me that a factory pattern would be more appropriate here (not templated allocate/reallocate)